# Can't click elements in my 'content' div

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have some text and a YouTube video on my website (aka: http://redstonegaming.com), and it won't let me start the video. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, when I set the content div to z-index: 99, it works but my dropdown menu goes under the content. Vice versa.

```js
var rick = false;
var audio = new Audio('rick_roll.mp3');
var kkeys = [],
  konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65,13";
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  kkeys.push(e.keyCode);
  if (kkeys.toString().indexOf(konami) >= 0) {
    kkeys = []; // <-- Change here
    if (rick == false) {
      rick = true;
      audio.play();
    } else if (rick == true) {
      rick = false;
      audio.pause(); // <-- another issue
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/*Some Fonts Here:*/
@font-face { font-family: Rusty; src: url('BrushScriptStd.otf');}
* {
 font-family: Rusty;
 font-weight: Lighter;
}
.background
{
 background-image: url(0.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-color: f7f7f7;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:absolute;
}
.menubar {
  height: 2.8vw;
  opacity: 0.85;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.menu-wrap {
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #3e3436;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Ek Mukta';
}
.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: #919191;
}
.menu li:hover > a,
.menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 0.95vw;
  line-height: 0%;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  float: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 0.7vw 5vh;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.menu > ul > li:hover > a,
.menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background: #2e2728;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
}
.sub-menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  transition: opacity linear 5.8s;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #2e2728;
}
.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: #3e3436;
}
.Rusty 
{
 font-family: "Rusty";
 color: rgba(189, 34, 34, 1);
}
.content
{
 opacity: .85;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
 z-index: -1; 
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 10px;
 height: 100%;
}
.menu > ul > .login 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.video-container {
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom:56.25%;
 padding-top:30px;
 width: 100%;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
 position:absolute;
 top:15;
 left:15%;
 right:15%;
 width: 25vw;
 height:25vh;
}
.title
{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 7vh;
 text-decoration: underline;
 -moz-text-decoration-color: inherit;
    text-decoration-color: inherit;
}
.feed-column
{
 width: 50%;
}
.text-center
{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-subscribe-widget-webp-vflj9zwo0.css"
    name="www-subscribe-widget" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title>RG - Home</title>
  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <div class="menubar">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li>
            <a href="aboutme.html">About Me 
            <span class="arrow">▼</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Gaming</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Programming</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">YouTube</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Other</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
          </li>
          <li class="current-item">
            <a href="#">
              <p class="rusty">RedstoneGaming</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="equipment.html">Equipment</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
          <li class="login">
            <a href="login.html">Login/Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="rusty title">ThatRedstoneGuy&#39;s Feed</h1>
      <div class="feed-column">
        <h1 style="font-size: 3vh;" class="rusty text-center">Colortone | Am I colorblind?! | W/Voiceless</h1>
        <div class="video-container">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-egJP-2ShRk?controls=2%20align="></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="feed-column">
   </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does the `.content` class include the rule `z-index: -1`? Have you tried removing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<body class="background">` is covering the `.content` div because you have `z-index: -1;` on the content class in your css file. You should be safe to just remove it, if not then change it to 1 and add `z-index: 2;` to your `.menubar` class.

You can see this in either Firefox or Chrome by using developer tools Inspect Element to see the layout of the page as it is rendered in the browser.

[Firefox Inspect Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector)

[Chrome Inspect Element](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/basics?hl=en)

EDIT:

After playing around for a while I found a solution. The z-index has some relation that I don't completely understand with whether the position is static or relative/absolute. So after experimentation I was able to get the menu to work properly by adding `position: relative;` to the `.menubar` class.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which option did you try and did it change anything?

Comment: I just removed the  z-index: -1;

Comment: Ok, then add z-index: 2; to the .menubar class and see if that fixes your menu.

Comment: See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djpianalto/3x9ze0vL/). The only thing I changed was z-index: 0; on the .content class and added z-index: 1; on the .menubar class.

Answer (score 1):

Your class specified here:

```
<div class="content">
```

is giving you this problem, maybe will conflict with an other same class name defined else where.

If I change this class name then your video works (just for testing purpose I have renamed to contents:

```
<div class="contents">
```

Check the diddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/te8sxvgq/

Comment: When I do that, the dropdown goes behind the video. Look [here](http://www.redstonegaming.com)